# PHP Open and edit existing .txt file

Tags: php, forms

I created a PHP form that creates a `.txt` file with a certain syntax. For example: When I enter mouse in text field number one and house in text field number to, it creates a .txt file with the following content:`"data1="mouse",data2="house"`.

So far so good. Now I would like to create another PHP site that shows every .txt file in a certain webfolder, displays each of those files with a checkbox to delete it. And here is my problem I don't know how to do that:

I want that each of the displayed file names is a hyperlink. If a user clicks on one of these links, it should read the .txt and take those elements I entered in my first PHP (mouse, house) and put it back into a form. So that I can edit and update existing .txt files.

Here is how far I have come, unfortunately I'm a lousy programmer. Has somebody done something like this before and could share the code?

```
<?php
include('auth.php');
$ordner = "txt/*";
$tablerows = "";
$i = 1;
foreach (glob("$ordner") as $filename) {
    if (isset($_POST['checkbox'][$i]))
        unlink(realpath($filename));
    $i++;
} $i = 1;
foreach (glob("$ordner") as $filename) {
    $tablerows .= "<tr><td>" . basename($filename) . "</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[$i]'></td></tr>\n";
    $i++;
}
?>

<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="main" style="padding:50px 0 0 0;">
                <!-- TERMINE LÖSCHEN FORMULAR -->
                <form id="formular" method="POST">
                    <h1>Termine löschen</h1>
                    <h2>Es wurde(n) <?php echo--$i - 1 ?> Termin(e) gefunden. </h2>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Datei</th><th>löschen</th>
                            </tr>    
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
<?php echo $tablerows ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Löschen" onclick="return confirm('Die ausgewählten Termine werden gelöscht! Sind Sie sicher?');">
                </form> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to do now, is making it possible to edit those .txt

Comment: Your code is hard to read, please format it properly.

Comment: It's hard to understand your requirements. Also your mix of PHP and HTML code is not the best choice how to write code. You'll get lost yourself sooner or later :)

Comment: `glob("$ordner")` no need for `"` there

Comment: To gain a better learning curve, skip that read/write files and head over to a database. Otherwise, php.net `file_put_contents()`, `file_get_contents()`

Comment: I'd recommend you checkout Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code instead of yours:

```
<?php
$path = "txt/*.txt";

// delete files
if (isset($_POST['delete']) && is_array($_POST['delete'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['delete'] as $filename) {
        unlink(realpath($filename));
    }
}

// prepare HTML table rows
$tablerows = "";
$i = 0;
foreach (glob($path) as $filename) {
    $tablerows .= "<tr>".
            "<td>" . basename($filename) . "</td>".
            "<td><input type='checkbox' name='delete[]' value='$filename'></td>".
        "</tr>\n";
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. What I am trying to do is to open a .txt file. Put specific parts of it into a form and if the form is submited, the .txt file should be updated. So something like the code below. My problem is, my text file has a specific format:

*data1="first text",data2="second text",data3="third text"*

I only want to read an exchange the parts between the ""! So if opened in a form, the first text input should have the word *first text* in it, the second one the word *second text*, and so on ... So when I change the content in the first text input to *test* and submit the form, my .txt file should then have the following content:

*data1="test",data2="second text",data3="third text"*

```
<?
if($_POST['Submit']){
$open = fopen("test.txt","w+");
$text = $_POST['update'];
fwrite($open, $text);
fclose($open);
echo "File updated.<br />"; 
echo "File:<br />";
$file = file("test.txt");
foreach($file as $text) {
echo $text."<br />";
}
echo "<p><a href=\"./livepage.php\">click here to view the live updated webpage</a></p>";
echo "<p><a href=\"./mainadminpage.php\">click here to view the admin menu</a></p>";
}else{
$file = file("test.txt");
echo "<form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<textarea Name=\"update\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"10\">";
foreach($file as $text) {
echo $text;
} 
echo "</textarea>";
echo "<input name=\"Submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\" />\n
</form>";
}
?>
```